# Correct and simplest syntactical way to initialise an array to 0

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to find out the correct way to initialise an array to all zeros (i.e. as if you have done a memset on the array).

I have found the following methods from various areas in stack overflow (and other sources):

```
char myArray1[10] = {0};
char myArray2[10] = {0,};
char myArray3[10] = {[0 ... 9] = 0};
char myArray4[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

I would prefer the simplest syntax variant... I was using {0}, but I have not found any proof this actually is correct.

Comment: So none of these ways work?

Comment: yes, they all seem to. But as I mentioned I found no proof that its actually correct!

Comment: well, except `{[0 ... 9] = 0};`, but its long winded

Comment: this post look like the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Comment: The third option is not legal C++. To be honest I’m not sure about the second either (but it seems to work even with `-pedantic`).

Comment: very similar... but for C only. Though the answer does seem to cover c++

Comment: @KonradRudolph I got the third option from: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Designated-Inits.html - maybe its compiler specific

Comment: @code_fodder The article you linked explicitly says that this is an *extension* and not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @KonradRudolph quite right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++ specification, "Aggregate initialization" (8.5.1):

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list.

So each `char` not in the initializer list would be initialized to `char()` that is `0`.

In C++11 you can type:

```
char a[10] = {};
char b[10]{};
```

Some old compilers (or was it in C) may require you add at least one member:

```
char a[10] = {0};
```

Naturally, if the array has static lifetime (global or static variable), then it will be zero initialized if there is not initializer:

```
char global_array[10];
```

I find it confusing, so I prefer to add the `= {}` anyway.

About the trailing comma, it is useful if you do something like:

```
char a[] = {
  1,
  2,
  3,
};
```

So that you don't make a special case for the last line and you make copy&paste and diffs easier. In your specific case is just useless:

```
char a[10] = {0,};
```

That comma does nothing, and it is ugly, so I wouldn't write it.

Comment: thanks for the spec quote :)

Comment: “In C++98, however” – are you sure about that?

Comment: haha....99 I think :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: No, I'm not sure. I think that it may be C99, not C++98. It was so long ago... I'll remove the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

Missing elements in an array will be initialised to 0. In addition, C++ allows you to leave the uniform initialiser empty. So the following works, is minimal and also the most efficient:

```
T array[N] = {};
```

It’s worth noting that this works for *any* type `T` which can be either default-constructed or initialised, not just built-in types. For example, the following works, and will print `foo` five times:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo() { std::cout << "foo()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    foo arr[5] = {};
}
```

A more extensive list of the different possibilities [was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/1968) by [aib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088/aib) some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this because it is simple yet explicit:

```
char myArray1[10] = { 0 };
```

Comment: It's better to remove the 0 because people might see it and think `{ 1 }` will fill it to 1s